# Why is template argument deduction/substitution failing for function templates only?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm experimenting with a class which is a wrapper of multiple modules. Each module needs some configuration. I try to solve this with a variadic template functions to ensure at compiletime, that each module which should be generated has it's configuration data given.

The only problem left is that the template argument deduction/substitution is failing for my creation function template. If the whole wrapper would be a templated class it would work.

Following I'm providing a little example of the problem. I tried to keep it as simple as possible.

```
class ClassA{};
class ClassB{};

template<class Module>
class FactoryModuleConfig;

template<>
class FactoryModuleConfig<ClassA>{
    public:
    FactoryModuleConfig(){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    virtual ~FactoryModuleConfig(){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};
template<>
class FactoryModuleConfig<ClassB>{
    public:
    FactoryModuleConfig(){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    virtual ~FactoryModuleConfig(){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

template< class... Args >
class FactoryConfig;

template<class Arg, class... Args>
class FactoryConfig<Arg, Args...> : public FactoryModuleConfig<Arg>, public virtual FactoryConfig<Args...>
{
    public:
        FactoryConfig(){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
        virtual ~FactoryConfig( ){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

template<>
class FactoryConfig<>
{
    public:
        FactoryConfig(){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
        virtual ~FactoryConfig( ){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

class myFactoryConfig : public FactoryConfig<ClassA,ClassB>{
 public: 
    myFactoryConfig(){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    virtual ~myFactoryConfig( ){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    int getNumberOfModules() const { return 1; } 
};

class Factory{
        Factory(){}
    public:
        virtual ~Factory(){}

        template<class ...Args>
        static Factory* create(FactoryConfig<Args...>* pCfg){ return new Factory();}
};

template<class ...Args>
class Factory2{
    public:
        Factory2(FactoryConfig<Args...>* pCfg){}
        virtual ~Factory2(){}
};

int main()
{
    // Solution 1
    myFactoryConfig* pCfg = new myFactoryConfig();                      // <-- why is this not working 
    // FactoryConfig<ClassA,ClassB>* pCfg = new myFactoryConfig();      // <-- and this works like a charm
    Factory* pfac = Factory::create<ClassA,ClassB>(pCfg);

    // Solution 2                                                       // Solution 2 is always working
    //FactoryConfig<ClassA,ClassB>* pCfg = new myFactoryConfig();       
    //Factory2<ClassA,ClassB>* pfac = new Factory2<ClassA,ClassB>(pCfg);  

    delete pfac;
    delete pCfg;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the example at coliru: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/744c58c7025c1c2f

I'm starting to doubt my c++ knowledge...

Comment: `new Factory2<ClassA,ClassB>` succeeds because *there isn't deduction*, you *must* specify all the parameters for the class template, so there can't be trailing `Args...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Solution without explanation as the previous one was incorrect, stil digging...*

---

You can solve this by making `FactoryConfig` only inherits `FactoryModule<>`:

```
template< class... Args >
class FactoryConfig: public FactoryModuleConfig<Args>...
{
    public:
        FactoryConfig() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
        virtual ~FactoryConfig() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};
```

Comment: Or as the Args are not relevant, just use a non variadic template `template<typename Config> static Factory* create(Config* pCfg)`

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I assumed this part of the code was simplified by OP for the question, otherwise I don't see a point in having this function templated, but this would be a good approach if `Args` are irrelevant. I still think that having a more flat hierarchy would be beneficial here.

Comment: True enough. Still odd to have all these virtual calls with templates at the same time. I would have assumed either ones would be enough.

Comment: Actually, as `Args` is specified, there should not be any confusion for the compiler as to which `create` to call.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Yes, I mixed up something while writting this answer... I've removed the explanation part and kept the solution as I think it's relevant anyway... Going to dig a bit deeper for the explanation!

Comment: As @Holt already stated, the part about the Args was simplified.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Holt, without doubt this a better solution for my problem. I'm gonna use it! I would still be interested in why this specific constellation does not work.

Comment: @theBro It might be a bug in gcc as other people have suggested. Since you've specified `<A, B>`, the deduction is equivalent to `create(FactoryConfig<A, B, Args...> *)`, which works with gcc... I've reduced your example to something more minimal https://godbolt.org/z/2I7cBU, maybe it's worth opening a bug or looking for a similar one.

Answer (score 1):

Compiles fine under clang, possibly a bug in gcc? See [g++ c++17 class template argument deduction not working in a very specific case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950967/g-c17-class-template-argument-deduction-not-working-in-a-very-specific-case/52986284) for a vaguely similar example.

Comment: This should really be a comment, and potentially flag it as a duplicate.  As is this isn't really an answer.

Comment: Indeed, seems like a gcc bug.

Comment: While this might be a bug (I have to dig through the standard), the linked answer is about class template argument deduction, which is irrelevant here.

Comment: Probably not the same bug, the linked bug involved parentheses.

Comment: I mostly linked it for the answer that says "This is a brand new feature in C++17, and therefore brand new in GCC."

Comment: @jakub_d Template argument deduction for functions is not something new.